# How to run a Selenium Perl script through XAMPP on OSX

Tags: perl, browser, selenium, xampp

Currently working with XAMPP server running on OSX. Also currently working with perl scripts that work with selenium. Is it possible to run the perl scripts through the xampp cgi-bin and have that launch the selenium tests? I would be ok with the output being in plain-text (I can fix that later)

The idea is to launch the selenium test scripts from a browser.

Comment: You mean like, you want a website where you can click something to start your tests for another website? Sounds simple.

Comment: Something like that. I tried a prototype, but it seems like the perl modules aren't being picked up correctly. ..

Error message: 
Can't locate HTTP/Request.pm in @INC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we ended up using an ANT script through Atlassian Bamboo to get this job done. We were deploying Bamboo for other maintenance and build issues anyways.

However, from the research I've done, it looks like Jenkins-CI (formerly Hudson-CI) is a free option that would be able to do the same thing, or very similar.